# Большое расстояние от легенды до графика при использовании plt.barh

Tags: python, matplotlib

Программка все рисует, но есть один момент. Для наглядности прикрепил 2 изображения.

Поясните, пожалуйста, откуда на *Рисунке 1* такое большое расстояние между верхней границей и баром для STO?

Сразу проясню, что оба графика выводятся одной функцией.

Рисунок 1:
[image: Рисунок 1]

Рисунок 2:
[image: Рисунок 2]

Comment: А можно пример кода? Как рисуется оно?

Comment: @Zelta, если подскажете как код вставить сюда, то да) у меня че-т не получается

Comment: @Markill Вставляете текст кода, нажимаете Ctrl + K, или добавляете по четыре пробела перед каждой строкой, оставив одну пустую строку, отделяющую код от остального текста.